# Working with React for the first time; PropTypes values are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's my first time working with React and I am trying to build a simple weather app to learn how components react with each other. I have a forecast.json file with the forecast information(temperature, date, humidity, wind speed, wind direction etc) and location.

I have built myself a ForecastDetails component that will display the values of these forecast variables and link it to my main app.jsx. The issue is every time I build my ForecastDetails component and try to render this component within my main App.jsx, I keep seeing PropType errors, which keep telling me the props I try to pass in the ForecastDetails component keeps coming back as undefined (I made sure they are required values through the importation of PropTypes).

Here is my main app.jsx file, which has the component ForecastSummaries(which takes the forecast value from a separate component called ForecastSummary)

```
import "../styles/App.css";
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import LocationDetails from "./locationDetails";
import ForecastSummaries from "./ForecastSummaries";
import ForecastDetails from "./ForecastDetails";

function App(props) {
  const { forecasts, location } = props;

  return (
    <div className="weather-app">
      <LocationDetails city={location.city} country={location.country} />
      <ForecastSummaries forecasts={forecasts} />
      <ForecastDetails forecasts={forecasts} />
    </div>
  );
}

App.propTypes = {
  // propType validation for forecasts data
  forecasts: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      data: PropTypes.number,
      description: PropTypes.string,
      icon: PropTypes.string,
      temperature: PropTypes.shape({
        max: PropTypes.number,
        min: PropTypes.number,
      }),
    }),
  ).isRequired,

  location: PropTypes.shape({
    city: PropTypes.string,
    country: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

// In React, component names MUST START WITH CAPITAL LETTERS

export default App;
```

Here is my ForecastDetails component;

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";

function ForecastDetails({ date, temperature, humidity, wind, description }) {
  return (
    <div className="forecast-details">
      <h1>Details</h1>
      <div className="forecast-details_date">
        {moment(date).format("ddd Do MMM")}
      </div>
      <div className="forecast-details_temperature">{temperature}&deg;C</div>
      <div className="forecast-details_humidity">{humidity}%</div>
      <div className="forecast-details_wind">{wind}mph</div>
      <div className="forecast-details_description">{description}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ForecastDetails.propTypes = {
  date: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  temperature: PropTypes.shape({
    min: PropTypes.number,
    max: PropTypes.number,
  }).isRequired,
  humidity: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  wind: PropTypes.shape({
    speed: PropTypes.number,
    direction: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default ForecastDetails;
```

For more context, here is the main index.js file that allows me to use the forecast data throughout my app and its components;

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./styles/index.css";
import App from "./components/App";
import forecast from "./data/forecast.json";

const { location, forecasts } = forecast;

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App forecasts={forecasts} location={location} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

[image: It should display the details below each Forecast Summary]

ı know the error is somewhere in how I am passing these props between components. However, It's really my first time with React so I don't really know how to identify the error itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use ForecastDetails which is written for a single forecast item. But you are passing the list of items instead.

Change your

```
<ForecastDetails forecasts={forecasts} />
```

To:

```
{forecasts.map((forecast) => <ForecastDetails {...forecast} />)}
```

Comment: Remember that components in arrays must have [keys](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key) (which in the vast majority of cases [can't just be the array index](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#where-to-get-your-key)).

Comment: I do remember that, but it's hard to select a key based on the information provided.

Comment: Still worth calling out, since people get this wrong All The Time... :-)

Comment: How do you decide what is going to be the key ?

Comment: @Erdem_Ayhan - You pick something from the `forecast` object that uniquely identifies the forecast. See [the link above](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#where-to-get-your-key). If the forecast doesn't have a unique identifier, consider adding one.